# GoogleMobileAds/DFPInterstitial.h' file not found

Tags: ios, google-ads-api, google-mobile-ads

GoogleMobileAds updation to latest version shows the below error with the version 9.

```
Showing All Errors Only
'GoogleMobileAds/DFPInterstitial.h' file not found
```

Comment: Is that a file you include?

Comment: No I am migrating my app from version 7 to version 9. While manually removed the existing framework and added the new xcframework in my app and fixed some of the deprecated and removed one. But the above s from that GoogleMobileAds import. #import <GoogleMobileAds/DFPInterstitial.h>

Comment: I guess you already cleaned the build folder and deleted derived data?  Do you have `#import <GoogleMobileAds/DFPInterstitial.h>` in your code?

Comment: Yes available in the code

Answer (score 0):

You commented that you have `#import <GoogleMobileAds/DFPInterstitial.h>` in your code and that this header file is not found.

I've [downloaded version 9.5.0 of the Google Mobile Ads SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download).  It turns out that this header file is no longer available.

This confirms what I thought had happened: Between version 7 and 9, Google has made large changes to its code and eliminated this header file.

What you need to do is figure out how your code uses the version 7 header file and find the replacement for version 9.  This means that you'll have to make changes to your code.  Often SDK designer make sure that required code changes are small; so it probably shouldn't be a big effort.

Comment: I have followed the migration guide https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/migration. It not available for the replacements. I am searching for this

Comment: @sejn If my answer helped you and describes your issue, then please up-vote and checkmark it.